# in R, is it possible to have NA as the minimum of ordered factor levels?

Tags: r

When using an ordered factor with NA as one of the levels, how to make NA the least (minimum) level?

Suppose I have a factor `z` of type ordered. Adding `NA` as one of the levels results in `NA` appearing as the highest (maximum) level.

```
z <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 7, replace=TRUE))
z[4] <- NA
z <- ordered(z)
z <- addNA(z)
min(z)           # A
max(z)           # NA
```

How to order the levels so that `min(z)` is `NA` and `max(z)` is "C"? The conventional manner of reordering drops the `NA`:

```
 z <- factor(z, levels = c(NA, "A", "B", "C"))
 levels(z)       # "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: Why do you need this behavior?  You can always create such an ordering yourself, outside the vector itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `exclude` and `ordered` arguments of `factor`:

```
set.seed(2017);
z <- factor(z, levels = c(NA, "A", "B", "C"), exclude = "", ordered = T)
#[1] <NA> A    C    A    C    B    B
#Levels: <NA> < A < B < C

min(z)
#[1] <NA>
#Levels: A < B < C
max(z)
#[1] C
#Levels: A < B < C
```

Comment: You're welcome @SunBee; please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
z=ordered(z,levels=c(NA,levels(z)),exclude=NULL)
> min(z)
[1] <NA>
Levels: A < B < C
> max(z)
[1] C
Levels: A < B < C
```